# how to access parent window object using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to acess parent window object using jquery?

This is my Parent window variable , I want to set its value after closing child window .

```
$('#serverMsg').html('some text here');
```

Answer (score 78, accepted):

```
window.opener.$("#serverMsg")
```

Comment: Works only if JQuery is active in the opener, I think.

Answer (score 18):

If you are in a po-up and you want to access the **opening window**, use `window.opener`. 
 The easiest would be if you could load JQuery in the parent window as well:

`window.opener.$("#serverMsg").html` // this uses JQuery in the parent window

or you could use plain old `document.getElementById` to get the element, and then extend it using the jquery in your child window. The following *should* work (I haven't tested it, though):

```
element = window.opener.document.getElementById("serverMsg");
element = $(element);
```

If you are in an iframe or frameset and want to access the parent frame, use `window.parent` instead of `window.opener`.

According to the Same Origin Policy, all this works effortlessly only if both the child and the parent window are in the same domain.

Answer (score 11):

or you can use another approach:

```
$( "#serverMsg", window.opener.document )
```

Comment: I prefer this approach because it doesn't rely on the opening window having jQuery - although it probably will have jQuery anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more literal answer (parent window as opposed to opener) to the original question that can be used within an iframe, assuming the domain name in the iframe matches that of the parent window:

```
window.parent.$("#serverMsg")
```