# jQuery select element in parent window

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, popup, parent

Is there a way to select a DIV in the parent window using jQuery?

For example:

Main page contains this,

```
<div id="testdiv"></div>
```

Popup page has a form with some options and an 'Apply' button. When the user clicks apply it affects the style attribute on the main page.

Something along the logic of,

```
parent.$("#testdiv").attr("style", content from form);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to access parent window object using jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167455/how-to-access-parent-window-object-using-jquery)

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Use the context-parameter

```
$("#testdiv",parent.document)
```

But if you really use a popup, you need to access **opener** instead of **parent**

```
$("#testdiv",opener.document)
```

Comment: Learned new thing today, Thanks :)

Answer (score 23):

I looked for a solution to this problem, and came across the present page. I implemented the above solution:

```
$("#testdiv",opener.document) //doesn't work
```

But it doesn't work. Maybe it did work in previous jQuery versions, but it doesn't seem to work now.

I found this working solution on another stackoverflow page:
[how to access parent window object using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167455/how-to-access-parent-window-object-using-jquery)

From which I got this working solution:

```
window.opener.$("#testdiv") //This works.
```

Comment: Awesome mate ! @Dr.Molle was overconfident !

Comment: ..or it actually worked in 2011. For this answer's solution to work, would that popup need to already have jQuery loaded?

Answer (score 4):

I came across the same problem but, as stated above, the accepted solution did not work for me.

If you're inside a frame or iframe element, an alternative solution is to use

```
window.parent.$('#testdiv');
```

[Here's a quick explanation of the differences between window.opener, window.parent and window.top:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313045/when-to-use-window-opener-window-parent-window-top)

- window.opener refers to the window that called window.open( ... ) to open the window from which it's called
- window.parent refers to the parent of a window in a frame or iframe element

Answer (score 2):

You can also use,

`parent.jQuery("#testdiv").attr("style", content from form);`

Comment: what if the iframe is in another domain? How to close it?

Answer (score 1):

why not both to be sure?

```
if(opener.document){
  $("#testdiv",opener.document).doStuff();
}else{
  $("#testdiv",window.opener).doStuff();
}
```