# Close new window from window which opened it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to close a window which have been opened in the following way:

```
var myWindow;
function openLink(){
    myWindow = window.open("http://mydir.com", "MsgWindow", "width=600, height=400, left=250, top=200");

    }
```

This opens a window inside a some kind of popup ([Here you can see how it works](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_open3))

What i want to do is when my ajax call finishes (in the opened window) close the window. I am trying with this:

```
 $.ajax ({
  url: "php/copia.php",
  type: "post",
  data: {"params": result,
  "dirDest":dirDest},
  success: function(response) {
        $.mobile.loading('hide');
        window.parent.postMessage('Close popup', '*');//I am trying to send a message to the parent window but it doesnt work
    }

});
```

In the window which opens the new window i have the following:

```
$( document ).ready(window.addEventListener("message", closePopup, false));

function closePopup(event) {
        myWindow.close();
    }
```

Comment: I think you need window.opener in stead of window.parent
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313045/when-to-use-window-opener-window-parent-window-top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution #1: just call `window.close()` in success callback.

Solution #2: replace `window.parent` with `window.opener`
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_opener.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_parent.asp

Read more here: [When to use window.opener / window.parent / window.top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313045/when-to-use-window-opener-window-parent-window-top)