# Check if window was opened by script in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, window

Is it possible to check if script opened a window with JavaScript?

I have User agreements and they are opened in a new window and when I try to close the window, this works:

```html
<a href="JavaScript:window.close()" class="btn btn-default">Return</a>
```

But what I would like to accomplish is that if the user go directly to `/agreeement` and clicks close, that it redirects him to the homepage.

Using my current code in this case, I get a message:

> Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.

And I understand why. That is why I would like to check whether the window was not opened from a script, and then redirect to index in that case.

Comment: `window.opener` returns `null` if there isn't an opener referrer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

window.opener will be null when the page is not opened by another window, and therefore can not be closed.

This code should should do the trick:

```
function goAway() {
    if(window.opener === null) {
        window.location.href = '<YOUR_DEFAULT_URL>';
    }
    else {
        window.close();
    }
}
```

You can find more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313045/when-to-use-window-opener-window-parent-window-top)

Comment: No it doesn't talk about != null ... it just explains what is window.opener... if you are a new developer reading that will not tell how to check if the page is opened by a script or a new window....

Comment: @Marcos Pérez Gude  Well i could delete this question then if thats a problem as i didnt knew how to approach this problem so i asked here

Comment: That's not a problem, we can mark as duplicated and the question will survive to the time, with the correct canonical reference.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since I've needed to do this, but you can get the window that opened the current window with [`window.opener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener)

Comment: Didnt knew that. Thanks will try this