# Why am I unable to reach parent window's variables?

Tags: javascript, window, browser-tab

Let's suppose I open a web-page and run this Javascript:

```
var test = "Success";
window.open(window.location.href);
```

Then, in the opened `window`

```
console.log(window.parent.test);
```

will yield `undefined`. I can solve the problem by doing this:

```
var test = "Success";
window.open(window.location.href).myParent = window;
```

and then, in the other `window`

```
console.log(test);
```

will yield `"Success"`. So, the problem can be solved, but I wonder why is the opened `window` unable to reach the parent `window`'s variables out of the box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried window.opener.test ?

or specifically: console.log(window.opener.test);

This link explains the difference between window.parent and window.opener:[When to use window.opener / window.parent / window.top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313045/when-to-use-window-opener-window-parent-window-top)