# Do I need to put rel="noopener" to each target="blank" even if the pointed website is from my own site?

Tags: html, security

When using a link with `target="__blank"`, it's recommended to add `rel="noopener"` too for security reasons.
But do I need it to add this even for the links pointing my own website?

```
<a href="internal/link/in/my/website" target="__blank>ClickMe</a>
<!--Do I need to add rel="noopener"?-->
```

Comment: NB: rel=noopener is now the default on most browsers, cf https://caniuse.com/mdn-html_elements_a_implicit_noopener

Comment: Yes for recent browsers, but for older one maybe it's a good idea to keep the rel="noopener" just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're pointing to your own site then no, if you're pointing to a third-party then it is recommended.

The reason being that `rel="noopener"` prevents the new page from being able to access the `window.opener` property and ensures it runs in a separate process.

You can read some more about `window.opener` here:
[When to use window.opener / window.parent / window.top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313045/when-to-use-window-opener-window-parent-window-top)