# How to clear the element in a open popup box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently I am using an click element to open a popup box to share some content on the social network

The code i used is :

```
$('#qq').attr("onclick", "window.open('http://sns.qzone.qq.com/cgi-bin/qzshare/cgi_qzshare_onekey?url=" + encodeURIComponent(location.href) + "&title=" + encodeURIComponent(shareDes) + "&pics=" + imgStr + "', 'QQshare','toolbar=0,status=0,width=800,height=500');");
```

Which generate a box , and in that box there is an textarea

```
<textarea class="view_summary"  id="summary" ><%=escHTML(summary)%></textarea>
```

How to clear the element inside it? I simply add `$('.view_summary').empty();` after the create box code, which does not work. Thanks

Comment: Try $('.view_summary').val('')

Comment: .empty() should work on textarea too. Can you replicate in a fiddle.? Here is one http://jsfiddle.net/jnPHr/

Comment: Thanks for answering but it is not working . Because it is not in the same page but in a pop up box? I tried $('.view_summary').is('*') return false and $('.view_summary').val() return undefined, thanks

Comment: Is the window using the same domain as the page with creates the window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the new window has the same domain as the page opening it then try

```
$('#qq').on("click", function(){
    var win = window.open('http://sns.qzone.qq.com/cgi-bin/qzshare/cgi_qzshare_onekey?url=" + encodeURIComponent(location.href) + "&title=" + encodeURIComponent(shareDes) + "&pics=" + imgStr + "', 'QQshare','toolbar=0,status=0,width=800,height=500');
    win.onload = function(){
        $('#summary', win.document).val('');
    }
});
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZZV0ZM3SvuyLoCPLR6ff?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure on this, but you might want to try $('#summary').empty();

Comment: Thanks for answering but it is not working . Because it is not in the same page but in a pop up box? I tried $('#summary').is('*') return false and $('#summary').val() return undefined, thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017796/jquery-select-element-in-parent-window  the second part of the selected answer looks to be what you need