# using jquery to select window.opener

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to access parent window object using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167455/how-to-access-parent-window-object-using-jquery)

I have the following jquery code

```
var events = $(window.opener).find("tr.athletics-date");
        var events_length = events.length;
```

I'm trying to retrieve all of the tr tags with class athletics-date from the parent page (which opened up the present new page) and its not working. The class name is correct, what am I doing wrong? events_lenth came up as 0!

Comment: i believe you want `window.opener.document` since window.opener gets you the parent window, not parent document. Not 100% sure though (otherwise i would make this an answer)

Comment: That did it! Thanks! you can post this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.opener` gives you the `window` object, you want the `document` object.

```
$(window.opener.document).find(...
```

Answer (score 0):

`window.opener.document` makes the difference.

Try this:

```
var events = $(window.opener.document).find("tr.athletics-date");
var events_length = events.length;
```