# How can I submit a form in a parent window using jQuery without refreshing the contents of the parent window (Ajax submission)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am attempting to submit a form contained in a parent window from a child iframe using jQuery without much luck.

In the child window I have the following validation function:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="templates/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="templates/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#form_invoice_item").validate({
            submitHandler: function (form) {

                // Check if main invoice already saved
                if ($('#invoice_id').val() == "") {

                    // Change target to processing iframe
                    try {
                        parent.$('#invoice_form').ajaxSubmit();
                    } catch(e) { //debug
                        alert ("Error:" + e);
                    }

                } else {
                    alert ("Saving invoice " + $('#invoice_id').val() + ' items');                         }

                //form.submit(); //debug
            }
        });              
    });
</script>
<form method="post" id="form_invoice_item" name="form_invoice_item" action="index.php" target="invoice_items">
```

The error that occurs at `parent.$('#invoice_form').ajaxSubmit();` is

> Error:TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'ajaxSubmit'

If I use the following snippet which is just in plain Javascript, there is no problem(Obviously this isn't jQuery but it gets the job done). How do i do this in jQuery:

```
parent.document.getElementById('invoice_form').target='process';
parent.document.getElementById('invoice_form').submit();
parent.document.getElementById('invoice_form').target='';
```

I have a hidden iframe called process which has its display property set to hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in a popup and you want to **access the opening window**, use `window.opener`.

Try this:

```
window.opener.$('#invoice_form').ajaxSubmit();
```

Instead of this:

```
parent.$('#invoice_form').ajaxSubmit();
```

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167455/how-to-access-parent-window-object-using-jquery) post.

**-------EDIT-----**

Don't forget to load jQuery form plugin in those window in which you call it:

`<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>`

Comment: This is not referring to a popup window so `window.opener` is not relevant. This is to do with iframes, so you need to refer to the parent using `window.document.parent` or using `$(parent)`

Comment: You are my hero! Adding <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> worked. Silly mistake on my part. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just use the parent selector:

```
$('#invoice_form',window.parent.document)
```

Comment: Thanks @ben-carey The object is found but the ajaxSubmit() is not a defined method for the object :( Perhaps I need to attach the ajaxSubmit method to the form by some other function call?

Comment: @DeAn That is probably because it is trying to run the function from the parent, you need to place the code for `ajaxSubmit()` into the parents javascript

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$(parent).find('#invoice_form').submit();
```

Comment: Thanks @roasted, It gets the object but doesn't submit the form... Well so it seems... Because no javascript error is caught by the try catch, nut when i check the network tab in the Chrome browser's inspector, there is no action

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
$(parent).find('#invoice_form').submit();
```