# How to call javascript function in parent page from child page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

If I have Two pages like this :

- Parent.aspx
- Child.aspx

The parent page Contains a textbox(`txt_grm`) and a button ,when the user click the button i execute the following code :

```
            Session["grm"] = txt_grm.Text;
            string queryString = "Child.aspx";//Popup window
            string newWin = "window.open('" + queryString + "');";
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "pop", newWin, true);
```

Now the Child page(popup) contains a `link button` with a specific text .

---

How to call a javascript function in the parent page from the child page given the link button text as a parameter to this function then close the child page?

Say  the link button in my child page :

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lkSelect" runat="server" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="8" ><%# Eval("Cell_Data") %></asp:LinkButton>
```

I want to call the following javascript function in my parent page and close my child :

```
 function DrawPaths(room) {
            for (var i in engin.pois) {
                if (engin.pois[i].getName(engin.getLanguage()) == room) {
                    engin.showPath(engin.pois[i].getNode(), engin.pois[i]);
                    break;
                }
            }
            engin.showFloor(getFloor(), callback)
        }
```

---

**Note :** `room` param is the link button text .

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311812/popup-window-accessing-parent-dom ?  window.opener in the client returns a handle to the parent.

Comment: Yes, you can use window.opener to call js.