# How to reload a text on parent window after submit on child's

Tags: javascript, java, xml, jsf, dom

I have this jsf button on my parent window:

The action opens a pop-up with another button, what I want is to reload the text associated with the parent button (Which is updated on java) without reloading all the page. I am trying this javascrit event on my child's screen button:

window.opener.document.getElementById('boton').location.relo‌​‌​ad()

But this is not working, how can I access to the parent page's button (or div) using javascript?

Comment: Maybe you can find some working answers here:<br> - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311812/popup-window-accessing-parent-dom<br> - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167455/how-to-access-parent-window-object-using-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:- (U need to get by formId:buttonId)

window.opener.document.getElementById('j_idt5:btn0').click();