# How to click on a button on a previous screen using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to click on the button on the previous screen by clicking on the button at the current screen
Writing method for clicking on the current button screen is easy (see below) but I have troubles finding the button on the previous screen.

```
$('body.printing').prepend('<input type="button" value="Retry" id="RetryLetter"/>');

    $("#RetryLetter").click(function()
    {
//          parent.history.back().$("#printLetter").click();
        var prButton =  document.referrer.getElementById("printLetter");
        prButton.click();
//          window.opener.$("#printLetter").click();
    });
```

I tried several variants – so far nothing worked

Comment: What do you mean by "current" and "previous screen"? Web pages? That's impossible... you can only interact with what exists. Before you try adventures calls such as `parent.history.back().$("#printLetter").click()` you should first read what `history.back()` is actually doing and returning: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.history.

Comment: But...what if that page is no longer loaded? How will you trigger a click on a page that is not (necessarily) being displayed

Comment: What do you mean previous screen? If its another page, the DOM is simply not loaded, you can't click it.

Comment: You cannot do anything on a page which is no longer loaded. also `document.referrer` returns a string so you cant use document methods on it

Comment: Yes, I mean previous pages. parent.history.back() returns me to the previous page but clicking does not work

Comment: Yeah parent.history.back() is just a reference to the previous page, but the previous page button does not exist in the context of the new page.

Comment: @Agush: It's not a reference to anything. It makes the browser load the previous page. That's a big difference (I guess you meant that though).

Comment: @anarinsky: JavaScript in one page can never affect the DOM or JS of another page (unless you load iframes from the same domain).

Comment: @FelixKling you are right, bad wording on my part. It's not a reference, it just toggles the back browser behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

document.referrer is just a string with the referring URL. It is not a DOM element that you can access.

http://wap.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_doc_referrer

Comment: If you open up a popup window however, you can access the parent window. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167455/how-to-access-parent-window-object-using-jquery

Comment: It looks that I need to load previous page again not using history

Answer (score 0):

So, it appeared that the only way to click on the button on the previous page is recreating the Get request from this button.
I memorize the request string (URL and parameters) in the session object and then repeat this request from the following page