# targeting the parent window using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Here is the sample code which I am not able to solve. I did it using javascript, but when I am doing using jQuery, I do not able to target the element.

Script :

```
var element = window.parent.document.getElementById('iframeOne');
//this is working fine
```

But i want to do using jQuery. So how can I target the element?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write this in jQuery "window.parent.document.getElementById('parentPrice').innerHTML"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726816/how-to-write-this-in-jquery-window-parent-document-getelementbyidparentprice)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to access parent window object using jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167455/how-to-access-parent-window-object-using-jquery)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps you want to do something like this

```
$('#iframeOne', window.parent.document);
```

Another way to do it

```
window.parent.$("#iframeOne");
```

Another way

```
$("#iframeOne", top.document);
```

If you know the name of the parent window, you can also do

```
$("#iframeOne",opener.document)
```

Here `opener` is the name of the window.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

to select element with id within the parent window

```
$('#iframeOne',window.parent.document);
```

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery selector syntax for id is to use a # before the id name

in you case it should be `$('#iframeOne')`

an optional context can also be used like `$('#iframeOne, window.parent.document)`. The default context is document root.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
var ele = $('#iframeOne', window.parent.document);
```

or

```
var ele = $(window.parent.document).find("#iframeOne");
```