# window.parent.document no longer working in safari

Tags: jquery, iframe, safari

I have a line of code in a page being loaded in an iframe that accesses an element in its parent window:

```
$('#titleBack', window.parent.document).fadeIn(500);
```

Both pages are in the same domain.  This works fine in Chrome and Firefox but crashes* in Safari.  From what info I can gather from people testing my site, this was working fine in Safari as of a few days ago.  Any ideas?

*No code beyond this line gets processed, however all the code up until this line is processed properly.

Comment: You may want to try [these alternative syntaxes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18372746/1647538).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `top.document` instead of `window.parent.document` fixes the problem.