# Have a frame trigger a function in its parent

Tags: javascript, html, html-frames

I have an HTML frame that I created by running `window.open('/a-new-page/', 'my-second-frame');` in the parent page.

When a button is clicked in the frame, I want to trigger a function on the parent page. (In my particular situation, the function updates some of the parent frames HTML)

What is the simplest way to do this?

Both the parent and the frame have the same domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the `window.parent` keyword from within your iframe you can gain access to elements in the parent window if the iframe and the parent window is on the same domain.

Try something like `window.parent.yourParentWindowFunctionName()` to call a function in the parent window.

Comment: Interesting, when I tried running parent.helloWorld() in my frame, it printed out my hello world message in my frame's console... not the parents. Will test again.

Comment: This, or, if he's using anonymous functions, in order to access the child context you can use `document.getElementById('my-second-frame').contentWindow.document`

Comment: Yeah I just tested it, and calling `parent.myFunction()` executes the parent's function in the frame that called it.  I tested it with `console.log()` - and the message showed up in my frame's console. Then I tested it with the function as `$('div').html('HI!');` which also replaces the div's content in my frame, not the parent.

Comment: Yes, if the call parent.helloWorld() did not return undefined then it called the function helloWorld() in your parent window. Do you mean your browser console when saying that it printed in your frame's console? If so then the console window picks up any console.log regardless of it coming from the parent or iframe.

Comment: Try parent.$('div').html('HI!'); instead to change content in the parent. As with the console.log, see my previous comment.

Comment: Hm, `parent.$('div').html('HI!');` still changes the div content in the frame, not the parent

Comment: Here's a comprehensive answer on this subject using jquery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18372746/targeting-the-parent-window-using-jquery

Comment: Wow - changing it to "opener.helloWorld()` works. Interesting that it's different from `parent.helloWorld()`.