# React Strict Mode and `window.open` side effect?

Tags: reactjs

I have a React component that uses a `useEffect` to open a popup window when the component is mount (the component is a screen).

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.open(...);
}, []);
```

With strict mode this ends up opening two popups. I know I could use a ref but this seems to circumvent the reason why React strict mode runs the effects twice. What would be a correct way to handle this with React resumability in mind?

Comment: Close the window in the cleanup function? A bit jarring on dev but that's the "correct" way to do it (without adding refs and complicating code just to appease the dev environment). Why are you opening a window on mount instead of an [a user action](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27088525/954940)? If I absolutely had to do it I'd probably put it in a `useOpenWindowOnMount(url)` hook so as to keep all the ugly (unnecessary) ref code all together in a neat little hook

Comment: Thanks @AdamJenkins, I can't close the window since that's not what the user would expect. I have to open it on mount because it's the result of a special redirect logic. I suppose refs are the only solution but it's so weird to need code just to circumvent a dev-mode behavior.

Answer (score -2):

To prevent the useEffect from running twice in React strict mode and still achieve the desired behavior of opening a popup window only once when the component mounts, you can use a ref to keep track of whether the effect has already been triggered.

Here's how you can do it:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const popupOpenedRef = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
 
    if (!popupOpenedRef.current) {
      window.open(...);
      popupOpenedRef.current = true;
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    // Your component JSX
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.