# new window how to get original window global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I use `window.open(...);` but the new window not get global variable of  original window,
so i only try many times as below

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="...."/></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href=".....css"/>
```

But the imported sources are too much,and they have to execute many program in these source such as go to server get json and deal with it or get excel and declare key and value into global variable in order to implements internationalization and so on.

How can i do this ?

**update**

i use `window.opener` and get original global variable,but the original method can not debug such as step into,and the css is not in new window,how can i slove it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to access parent window object using jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167455/how-to-access-parent-window-object-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `window.opener` in your opened window

Comment: nice one. Check out http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_opener.asp for more info

Comment: yes,but css not get from original window..is there some solution?