# loading content in a div from iframe with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, load, external

I have a dropdown list menu in my "index.php" page that loads another page (depending of selection) in a iframe like this:

```html
<head>
<script language="javascript">

function setPic(elem) {
     var image = document.getElementById('canvas');
     image.src = elem.value; 
  
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="header">
loading area
</div>


<div id="content">
  <form>
    <select onchange="setPic(this);">
      <option value="/network/page_elements/lvl1.php" >lvl1</option>
      <option value="/network/page_elements/lvl2.php" >lvl2</option>
      <option value="/network/page_elements/lvl3.php" >lvl3</option>
      <option value="/network/page_elements/lvl4.php" >lvl4</option>
    </select>
</form>


<iframe src="/network/page_elements/lvl1.php" id="canvas"></iframe>

</div>
</body>
```

So i am loading for example page "lvl1.php" in the iframe. This "lvl1.php" page contains a button like this:

```html
<form method="post">
  <input type="button" value="1" id="A1" />
</form>
```

When this button is being pressed it executes a jquery code that should load some results in the div with id="header" on the "index.php" page...wich it doesn't.

The jquery looks like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
  
    $('#header').load('network/page_elements/header.php');
 
 $('input').click(function() {
  
  var page=$(this).attr('id');
  
  $('#header').load('network/buttons/' + page + '.php');
  });
  
  return false;
});
```

So in this example when button is pressed it should execute a script called "A1.php" and post its results in the div with id="header" on the index page.

If i place the button code on the "index.php" page it works fine...but it does nothing if it is being pressed on the loaded page inside the iframe.

Any ideea what am i doing wrong?

Comment: $('input') instead use $('#A1').click

Comment: there will be more buttons....A1 is just an example...so i cant use it specific for this button only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must access the DOM of the parent window since the javascript is executing inside a frame

```
window.opener.$("#header")
```

[how to access parent window object using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167455/how-to-access-parent-window-object-using-jquery)

Comment: i modified the jquery like this: $(document).ready(function() {
 
  
    window.opener.$('#header').load('network/page_elements/header.php');
 
 $('input').click(function() {
  
  var page=$(this).attr('id');
  
 
  window.opener.$('#header').load('network/buttons/' + page + '.php');
  });
  
  return false;
});
 but it still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Got it in the end:

I changed the jquery like this to access the parent window:

```js
$("#header",window.parent.document).load('/network/buttons/' + page + '.php');
```

Thanks for the idea Digitaldouble