# It is slow to query the element of the parent window in ie11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, dom

It is slow to query the element of the parent window in ie11
Chrome and Firefox are very fast.
Why does this happen?

- IE11

```
console.time('get');
$(opener.document).find('#listCount').text();
console.timeEnd('get');
```

result : 310.9ms

---

- CHROME

```
console.time('get');
$(opener.document).find('#listCount').text();
console.timeEnd('get');
```

result :  2.22ms

Comment: Because IE is slow! It uses heavy objects where modern browsers use light weight objects.

Comment: And this? `window.opener.$("#listCount").text()` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167455/how-to-access-parent-window-object-using-jquery

Comment: Thank you very much. I solved the problem.